# Trying to access this to query. First timer using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a single document.  Here is my current code.  Been on this for hours and can't seem to get it to work.  Bet its an easy fix

```
export function GetSingleTicket() {
  const docRef = doc(db, "tickets", "hg7G40Lhwh9HVwqe4mlB");

  getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);
  });
}
```

[image: firebase document tree]

Comment: The collection name is spelled `Tickets` with an uppercase `T`, but your code has it as `ticket` with a lowercase `t`. Collection names are case-sensitive, so they need to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you, this makes me want to cry

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Frank van Puffelen [Property names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=web#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20user%20property%20names%20are%20case%2Dsensitive%20and%20that%20setting%20two%20user%20properties%20whose%20names%20differ%20only%20in%20case%20results%20in%20two%20distinct%20user%20properties%20being%20logged) are case-sensitive. And according to your code the collection name is in small letters.

Solution:

```
export function GetSingleTicket() {
  const docRef = doc(db, "Tickets", "hg7G40Lhwh9HVwqe4mlB");

  getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data(), doc.id);
  });
}
```